# C: How to read in multiple values using scanf in a matrix

Tags: c, matrix, scanf

Hi I'm trying to write a code for user input matrix size and values. I got the bit about setting the matrix size and value, but I want to read in one row at a time so that I don't have to press enter every time after a single value input. This is my code so far. Thanks.

```
int row, col, i, j;
int mat[10][10];

printf("Enter number of rows: ");
scanf("%d", &row);
printf("Enter number of columns: ");
scanf("%d", &col);

for (i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
        scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("\nHere is your matrix:\n");   
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {  
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {  
        printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);  
    }  
    printf("\n");  
}
```

Comment: You can enter with a space delimiter.

Comment: Try giving e.g. `1 2 3 4 5` as input *on a single line*... What the `"%d"` format with `scanf` read is actually *white-space delimited* decimal numbers. And newline is a white-space, as is normal space.

Comment: You can also search **C array scanf user input** here on StackOverflow and come up with 1000's of examples `:)`

Comment: OH that works. I never thought about that way. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!

Comment: To cut down on your typing when debugging your code, you can also simply create a text file holding your values and redirect it as input to your code (e.g. `./yourprog < yourdata.txt`)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to read in one row at a time so that I don't have to press enter every time

The code you listed can work this way! That's how scanf works.

You CAN press an Enter once each number or once each row(you should use space or tab to delimit numbers) or even after you input the whole matrix, just try it!

Comment: @sKrellish: You could even type `3+3+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9` on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

In C  Memory is allocated continuously

The values will be stored in the array row wise so use space instead of new line it will work

Even if you type all elements on one line separated by space it will store row wise

so if
rows=3 col=3

i/p=  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
matrix will be

1  2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

Comment: Your explanation is irrelevant: the order in which values are converted in the loop is solely determined by the code, not the way memory is laid out. Values converted by `scanf("%d", ...)` can be separated by any amount of white space characters: spaces, tabs, newlines, even form feeds and vertical tabs. The values for row, col and all matrix values can be typed on a single line or spread over many lines, it does not matter.